# Trig Equations Using Identities

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How would you solve:

> $2\csc^2x=3\cot^2x-1$

I said:

> 1. Turn the **cosecant** to $1+\cot^2~x$.
> 2. Distribute to get $3=\cot^2~x$.
> 3. Turn it into **tan**. To get $\tan x=\frac{1}{\pm \sqrt3}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes your idea is good and from $\tan{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ you get $x=\frac{\pi}{6}+k \pi,$ $k \in Z$ and from  $\tan{x}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}$ you get $x=\frac{-\pi}{6}+k \pi,$ $k \in Z.$ So the set of solutions is $$S=\left\{\frac{-\pi}{6}+k \pi, \frac{\pi}{6}+k \pi, k \in Z\right\}.$$

Comment: Yes you are right @André but I checked and it worked.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that pi/6 is equal to that.

Comment: Never mind, 1/sqrt(3) is sqrt(3)/3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is ok.

Another approach:

$$2\text{cosec}^2x = 3(\text{cosec}^2x -1) -1 = 3\text{cosec}^2x -4 $$

$$  \text{cosec}^2x-4= 0$$

$$ \frac{1}{\sin^2x} = 4$$

$$ \sin^2x = \frac{1}{4}$$

$$ x = k\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{6} $$

Comment: Yes, so you are saying that tan x = 1/sqrt(3) has no rational answer?

Comment: that's also ok-sry, will edit my post.

Comment: No problem, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Notice, we can also solve this as follows $$2\csc^2 x=3\cot^2 x-1$$ $$\implies \frac{2}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{3\cos^2 x}{\sin^2x}-1$$ $$\implies 2=3\cos^2 x-\sin^2x$$ $$\implies 3\cos^2 x-(1-\cos^2x)=2$$ $$\implies 4\cos^2 x=3$$ $$\implies \cos^2 x=\frac{3}{4}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2$$ $$\implies \cos^2 x=\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^2$$ Now, writing the general solution as follows 
$$\implies \color{blue}{x=n\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{6}}$$ Where, $\color{blue}{\text{n is any integer}}$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

For convenience and speed in latexing  I abbreviate/algebraize trig functions, pushing their arguments into suffix position:

$$  \frac{2}{s_x^2}= 3(\frac{1}{s_x^2} -1) -1 = \frac{3}{s_x^2} -4 $$

Simplifying you get:

$$ s_x = \pm \frac12  ;\,  x = n\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{6}. $$